# Sending a message in a discord channel without events using PYTHON and DISCORD.PY leave running the other part of the code

Tags: python, discord, message, send

I'm wondering on how to send a message in a specific channel using PYTHON and DISCORD.PY library.
I'm just a little bit confused.
I wrote a piece of code running correctly under python-binance library and sending messages via telegram library without any issues. The messages are sent when some conditions are met in the code without any telegram events, so the code is not locked in any point of the program.
I need to achieve the same target but using discord instead.
I'm not able to do so because I cannot find any example of this type.
Could someone lights up an idea or a piece of code for me?
Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: I have no idea what is your problem. Better show your code and we will see what you means.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():

    channel = client.get_channel(<channel_id>)

    await channel.send("Hello World")

client.run("<your_token>")
```

Insert your values ​​in <channel_id> and <your_token>, after this, execute the code in terminal.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

```py
# You can get the channel ID by enabling developer mode
# and right-clicking on the channel and clicking "Copy ID"
channel = client.get_channel(12324234183172)
# Normally you would await, but since you want to leave your code running
channel.send('Here is your message')
```

Comment: Yes, sure, but I'm searching a complete working example...

Comment: @mikeardy you can find many working examples in tutorials, blogs, video tutorials (on YouTube) and even in other questions on Stackoverflow. You could start at discord [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which have link to examples in [repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/v2.0.1/examples)

Comment: This would result in an error. As well, you should leave explanations outside of code blocks. Lastly, you should avoid answering low-quality questions, as these are often not useful for future readers and by extension neither are the answers.